# Angular 2 ngClass is not Updating on View

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular2-template

I'm having some difficulty getting ngClass to update my view, even though the back end is updating properly. My controller is as follows:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'show-hide-table',
    template: '
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th (click)="toggleHidden()">
                    <div>Show/Hide</div>
                </th>
                <th [ngClass]="{\'hidden\':isHidden}">
                    <div>Div is Shown</div>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>',
    styleUrls: ['show-hide-table.component.css']
})

export class ShowHideTable implements OnInit, OnChanges, DoCheck {
    public isHidden: boolean = false;

    public toggleHidden() {
        this.isHidden = !this.isHidden;
        this.log.debug('Hidden', this.isHidden);
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes: {[propKey: string]: SimpleChange}) {
        this.log.debug('Grid Changes');
    }

    ngDoCheck() {
        this.log.debug('Grid Check');
    }
}
```

'hidden' is a css class with display: none. When I default isHidden to true, the header is hidden, and when false, it is shown, so I believe the class is working. I simplified it for sake of asking, but this should accurately reflect my code. I click the header and I get a log showing the isHidden variable toggling, but the hidden class isn't changing to suit. Also, neither ngOnChanges nor ngDoCheck is firing when the clickable header is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You've got too many pairs of single quotes.  The quotes around 'hidden' actually end the first string and start another one.  You've got to escape those quotes.

```
<th [ngClass]="{\'hidden\':isHidden}">
```

I can't test this but it should work.  If for some reason it doesn't you could try using Javascript encoding of the quotes.  Replace the single quote with `\x27`.

Comment: Ah, my template is actually in a template file, so there isn't any string escaping going on, but you're correct here. I'll edit my post to remove that mistake.